# Result of ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I used this kind of Ajax call found on [this site](http://www.a2zwebhelp.com/multiple-file-upload). The purpose is to upload multiple files without refreshing the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    new multiple_file_uploader
    ({      
        form_id: "fileUpload", 
        autoSubmit: true,
        server_url: "../ajax/myfile.php" // PHP file for uploading the browsed files
    });
});
</script>
```

And I try to store the result of this ajax call. I do not really know how to proceed.

I am used to work with this kind of syntax

```
$.post("../ajax/myfile.php",
{
  var1: "var1",
  var2: "var2",
},
function(data,status)
{ 
  var result = data;
  //Use result as you wish
});
```

Which is more understandable ...

I tried to convert the first ajax to the second. But it make the whole page failing. I am pretty sure that the result can be easily stored without changing everything

Comment: you get the reponse of ../ajax/myfile.php which can be your echo's for example (`echo "succesfully send file";`)

Comment: The documentation for your library doesn't say, so you're essentially asking us to reverse engineer 250 lines of JS.

Comment: @Thomas — And how do you do that using the API of the multiple_file_uploader library that the OP is asking about?

Comment: @Quentin my bad, I misread "I am used to work with this kind of syntax"

Answer (score -1):

I have check the library. It seams ity doesnt provide any callback option.

Basically, you cant store result.